# The time derivative of any solution to the wave equation is also a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Show that the time derivatives, $v= \frac {\partial u} { \partial t}$, of any solution to the wave equation is also a solution. If you know the initial conditions of $u$, what initial conditions does $v$ satisfy?

I am having a hard time with this question because I do not get what are they are asking me to do. I am confused with the question itself.

Comment: Do you know the wave equation?

Comment: A good start would be to write the equation down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to state the wave equation and assume you have a solution $u(x,t)$ (or maybe in more dimensions, but do the 1D case first).  Now define $v(x,t)=\frac {\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$.  Take the partial derivative of the wave equation with respect to $t$.  You should find some terms that you can argue are $v(x,t)$ and note that the equation they satisfy is the wave equation.